# Folium - Django: How to make a folium marker a link to another page

Tags: python, django, leaflet, folium

I'm generating a map using Folium with Django like so:

`views.py`:

```py
def viz(request):
    dg_map= folium.Map(location=[50.38175,6.2787],               
              tiles= 'https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?api_key=<MY_API_KEY>',
              attr= '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
              zoom_start=10)
    map_details = fetch_data("SELECT id, firstname, lat, long FROM map_details") #helper func to query the DB
    for item in map_details:
        location = [item[2], item[3]]
        popup = f"{item[1]}'s Garden"
        marker = folium.Marker(
            location = location, 
            popup = popup, 
            icon=folium.Icon(color='darkgreen', icon="heart", prefix='fa'))
        marker.add_to(dg_map);
    m = dg_map._repr_html_()
    context = {'map': m}
    return render(request, 'accounts/viz.html', context)
```

This is working as expected.

However, I'd like each marker to redirect towards another page on-click. To make matters worse, I'd need to use the `id` that's queried in the SELECT statement and include it in the destination link, because the urlpattern of the destination pages is this:

`urls.py`:

```py
path('garden/<str:id>/', views.garden, name="garden").
```

What I found out so far:

- I found several suggestions on how to add an href to the pop-up (e.g. [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/616)) but this is not what I want as it requires the user to click twice.
- Some ideas on how to add custom js to Folium's output are mentioned [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/86), but I think it's not implemented yet.
- I also found [instructions](https://jsfiddle.net/8282emwn/) on how this can be done in Leaflet. It seems pretty straight forward, but I'd like to stick with Python/Folium code and keep the logic in my `views.py` rather than starting js scripting.

Any idea how this can be achieved? Thanks a lot!